# Speed difference between SplFileInfo->getFilename() and getBasename()

Tags: php, performance

After searching for a while on the internet, I see that there is barely any difference between the results of using `SplFileInfo->getFilename()` and `SplFileInfo->getBasename()`.

That brings me to the following question: Is there any speed difference between using this one of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Yes, `getFilename()` seems to work faster.

Long version:

So, I made the following test environment:

```
$file = new SplFileInfo('test');

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { $file->getFilename(); }
$end = microtime(true);
$seconds = $end - $start;
echo "getFilename $seconds seconds.".PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { $file->getBasename(); }
$end = microtime(true);
$seconds = $end - $start;
echo "getBasename $seconds seconds.".PHP_EOL;
```

I performed both methods 1.000.000 times after each other and executed the code several times. Execution times are displayed in seconds. These are the results:
[image: Test results]

**Conclusion:** `getFilename()` seems to work a little bit faster. Approximately 7%. Maybe it has something to do with the optional parameter for `getBasename()` that makes it a little bit slower.

Comment: Looking into the php source, [getFilename](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a7fe2570d3ce6915d4ea85c62c0f880ddc225ba7/ext/spl/spl_directory.c#L896) simply looks at the path and returns the last part, whilst [getBasename](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a7fe2570d3ce6915d4ea85c62c0f880ddc225ba7/ext/spl/spl_directory.c#L999) calls [basename()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/64002648562362b97fcb78b68366b1b2118ffd5b/ext/standard/string.c#L1542)'s code, which can handle the prefix parameter and there is alot more logic involved. So thats why its slightly faster.